# new apt tool cache *.deb files

Tags: apt

How the new apt tool can cache the *.deb files as well as apt-get ? 
How the new apt tool can cache the *.deb files as well as apt-get ? 
How the new apt tool can cache the *.deb files as well as apt-get ?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK both apt and apt-get read from the same cache in `/var/cache/apt/archives/`